# Can an OAuth scope confirmation screen have a choice for the user?

Tags: oauth, openid

I'm quite new to OAuth and looking at a idea for a service where users have a number of item profiles. I would like the user to be able to authorize access to certain information in one item profile but not others. So rather than just a list of text scopes on an authorization view, is it possible to display a list of profiles where they can select the one they want to share access to? And can that information be passed back the client app?

A similar analogy might be that a client app could be allowed detailed access to a single GitHub organisation, but not to any other orgs a user is a member of.

Answer (score 0):

The third paragraph of [3.3. Access Token Scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) says as follows.

> The authorization server MAY fully or partially ignore the scope
> requested by the client, based on the authorization server policy or
> **the resource owner's instructions**.  If the issued access token scope
> is different from the one requested by the client, the authorization
> server MUST include the **"scope" response parameter** to inform the
> client of the actual scope granted.

So, authorization server implementations may enable resource owners to choice scopes. Also, you can expect `scope` parameter comes back along with an access token when scopes granted actually are different from the ones requested originally by a client application.